# Wordpress admin-ajax.php what is search parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am new to php and wordpress.
On admin-ajax.php is there a search parameter i can add ?
These parameters are in the ajax post;

```
action: rblivep
data[uuid]: uid_search_0
data[name]: grid_small_1
data[posts_per_page]: 8
data[pagination]: infinite_scroll
data[crop_size]: foxiz_crop_g1
data[entry_category]: bg-1
data[entry_meta][]: date
data[review]: replace
data[sponsor_meta]: 1
data[entry_format]: bottom
data[excerpt_source]: tagline
data[paged]: 1
data[page_max]: 28
data[processing]: true
data[page_next]: 2
search_query: phones
```

I added this to the paramters to return only search results but it did not worked.
`search_query: phones`

No matter what paramter i added i couldn't get it to give the search results.

Answer (score 1):

I actually find the right answer.

```
data[s]='phones'
```

In my case i needed to add this to ajax data.